# ltrim function doesn't work as expected ? php

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.4, php-5.5

I am using [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) function.
I run this code :

```
echo ltrim("looooooooooooooooooooooooongWord","long");
```

i expect to get this word : `looooooooooooooooooooooooongWord` but it prints `Word`.

what's the problem ?

Edit:
I thought it remove the word long, but it appears it remove the l,o,n,g characters !

Comment: Please take effort in reading the PHP documentation, the functions' description is quite clear in this. It's a "character mask"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ltrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a
>   string

It does exactly as it says, strips chars l, o, n, g.

Comment: I thought it cut the word long.

Comment: @david I don't really understand how you got this idea from documentation.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: (please read them).

```
string ltrim ( string $str [, string $character_mask ] )
```

**str**

The input string.

**character_mask**

You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.